# SQL Substring to fetch values which inside Bracket only i.e. ()

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

Might be easy for you expert but I am finding a challenge here-
My column data is as like below, I need to separate out the value which is inside bracket(). My string pattern would always be like this.

```
J Zeneta (A50103050); S Rao (B499487)
```

Output should be

```
Col1        Col2
A50103050   B499487
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Are you saying that "J Zeneta (A50103050); S Rao (B499487)" is a single string/varchar value in a single column in a single row?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it might need tweaking depending on your RDBMS, this is for SQLServer

```
select Left(value, CharIndex(')',value)-1) from (
    select value from String_Split('J Zeneta (A50103050); S Rao (B499487)','(')
    where value like '%)%'
)x
```

Edit

To have columns a simple `case` can yeild, like so

```
select max(case when rn=1 then Value end) Col1, max(case when rn=2 then value end) Col2 from ( 
    select Left(value, CharIndex(')',value)-1) [Value], Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) rn from (
            select value from String_Split('J Zeneta (A50103050); S Rao (B499487)','(')
            where value like '%)%'
    )x
)x
```

Edit 2

Using data from an existing table example

```
create table #Test (id int, col varchar(50))
insert into #Test select 1, 'J Zeneta (A50103050); S Rao (B499487)' 
insert into #Test select 2, 'Bob Builder (12345); Mr Rambo (67890)'

select id, max(case when (rn % 2)=0 then Value end) Col1, max(case when (rn % 2)!=0 then value end) Col2 from ( 
    select id, Left(value, CharIndex(')',value)-1) [Value], Row_Number() over (order by (select null)) rn from (
            select id, value
            from #Test t cross apply String_Split(t.col,'(')
            where value like '%)%'
    )x
)x
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks @Stu, this is pretty much close, however the output should appear as Columns rather than in rows. Please suggest.

Comment: Your output in your question has rows?

Comment: apologies, I think it is auto appeared as rows in question, hence I mentioned Col1 Col2 please.

Comment: Ok that's not hard to do, have updated above :)

Comment: apologies again, but where I should give Table.Column referece as the string I gave for example but it is some Column in a Table to run the query as TSQL

Comment: Final edit with example of using text in an existing table

Comment: Thanks, but getting the issue [Invalid object name 'String_Split'.], was more looking to achieve this with substring and charindex options.

Comment: You've tagged SQLServer and this works for me on SQL2016+ hopefully you're not on an older version. Assuming 2016 or newer have you checked database settings for compatability level

Comment: It's SQL server v 17.4 version